# How do I parse a path alias?

Tags: 7, uri, path-aliases

I have the following code in my `page.tpl.php` file.

```php
<?php $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']); ?>
<?php if ($path == 'about-us'): ?>
  <div class="container">
    <h1> about us!!!!</h1> 
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works for `/about-us`, but not for `/about-us/abc`.

What code would work for all the paths under `/about-us`?

I've messed around with `arg()`, but I ended up with a page error.

Comment: This seems to be a question about PHP and not specifically about Drupal. Have a look at the available string functions in PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Answer (score 1):

```
// Retrieve an array that contains the path pieces.
$path_args = arg();

// Check if the current page is the page you're looking for.
if ($path_args[0] == 'about-us') {
  // Your code.
}
```

Comment: You mean `$path_args[0]`?

Comment: @leymannx yes, thanks